# import text in multi-dimensional array in python

Tags: python

I know how to import text from a file in an array and also how to remove "\n" at the end of each line but I don't know how to have a list of sublist, each sublist containing each lines. I need to load a grid to cipher it.

**example:**

line 1: 101\n

line 2: 010\n

line 3: 110\n

->  I want to obtain this result [   [1,0,1] , [0,1,0] , [1,1,0]   ]

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
text_file = r"/path/to/your/file/"
definitive_list  = []
array = []

with open(text_file, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()
        for digit in line:
            array.append(digit)
        definitive_list.append( array )
        array = []
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, just have to return definitive_list and it works, good job.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in just two lines.

```
with open('path/to/file') as f:
    line_lists = [list(line.strip()) for line in f]
```

`list` on a `str` object will return a list where each character is an element. `line` is stripped first, which removes leading and trailing whitespace. This is assuming that you actually want the characters as `char`. If you want them parsed to `int`, this will work:

```
with open('path/to/file') as f:
    line_lists = [[int(x) for x in line.strip()] for line in f]
```

Mind you that there should be some error checking here, the above example will crash if any of the characters cannot be parsed to int.